# How to ensure than an extension's pageAction shows for pre-rendered pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, prerender

I am developing a Chrome extension with a `pageAction` for a specific site. I would like to convert my extension to use an event page instead of a background page.

I found pre-rendered pages were slipping through the suggested methods I read about for displaying them. The only way I could find to make the `pageAction` show on pre-rendered pages, was to listen to the `chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced` event, and additionally display the `pageAction` if the replacing url was correct there. Since the listeners for this event do not support filters, my listener is being called on every pre-render, and thus would be waking up if it were an event page.

Is there an alternative way to make sure my `pageAction` shows in the case of prerendered pages?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround and perhaps better solution. I am now using the html5 api for detecting visibility state. If it is visible I send a message to the backgroundPage to display the pageAction. This effectively replaced all the other code I had for displaying the pageAction.

Hopefully this will help others out there.

```
//contentScript.js
//This sections is to handle when we want to display the pageAction icon
function handleVisibilityChange(){
  if (!document.webkitHidden){
    //the page is now visible and is therefore not prerendering or in the background
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({message: "pageLoaded", userLoggedIn: loggedIn()}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);});
  }
}

document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);

//Call the function incase the document is already visible/
handleVisibilityChange();

//backgroundPage.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.message == "pageLoaded"){
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"}); //close the connection.

      console.log('detected page load');
      if(request.userLoggedIn == true){
        //Show regularPageAction
        console.log('user logged in so showing pageaction normal');
        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({tabId: sender.tab.id, popup: "popup.html"});
      }
      else{
        //show non logged in page action.
        console.log('user now logged in so showing pageaction non normal');
        chrome.pageAction.setPopup({tabId: sender.tab.id, popup: "notLoggedIn.html"});
      }
      chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  }
  });
```